# Git - adding ignore files to the .gitignore does not work

Tags: github

when I do a git push -f

My ignore files are also pushed to the online repository at https://github.com/

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

I have added the file extensions to the .gitignore file like so;

.Web.config

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: `git push` will only push what has been committed. What do you see as committed when you do `git status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question, but as far as I got, you have something like this:

```
.
├── .gitignore
└── something.Web.config
```

And you want to ignore `something.Web.config` by adding it in the `.gitignore`

and you tried it by adding just `.Web.config` in the content of `.gitignore`

Well, if I got it right

Just add the * at the beginning, something like:

```
*.Web.config
```

if you add it without the `*`, git will exclude files which full name is `.Web.config` but it seems it's not your case.

Also, make sure `.gitignore` is located in the right place, and not in a subfolder, but in the root of the project

Answer (score 1):

I use * as well, like so:

*.pdf

*.png

... and usually you don't need the -f flag for `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if a file has been imported into git before it’s added to .gitignore you’re too late.

You have to remove the files from git using git rm and then commit and from then on, they will be ignored.